# Strange CPack behaviour

Tags: windows, cmake, nsis, cpack

I'm having a problem with `CPack` but I don't quite understand what the problem is. In the `installer.cmake` file I have the following lines:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# set the variables for the call to CPack

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "Kappa")
set(CPACK_NSIS_PACKAGE_NAME "Kappa")
set(CPACK_NSIS_DISPLAY_NAME "Kappa")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "A great app.")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY ${PACKAGING_DIR})
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "Me")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR 19)
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR 2)
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH 12)
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/eula_licence.txt")

include(CPack)
```

When I run this code `CPack` fails with this warning:

```
EXEC : CPack error : Problem running NSIS command: "C:/Program Files (x86)/NSIS/makensis.exe" "D:/Workspace/Packaging/_CPack_Packages/win
64/NSIS/project.nsi" [D:\Workspace\build_fixed\package.vcxproj]
EXEC : CPack error : Problem compressing the directory [D:\Workspace\build_fixed\package.vcxproj]
EXEC : CPack error : Error when generating package: Kappa [D:\Workspace\build_fixed\package.vcxproj]
```

If I change the following lines as follows, it also throws the same error:

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "19")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "2")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "12")
```

However, if I change the following lines as below:

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "X")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "Y")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "Z")
```

then everything works and the package is compiled as `Kappa-X-win64.exe`.

I really don't understand why it can accept letters but not numbers or numbers as characters. I'm really confused by this. I can obviously just leave it with the XYZ but I'd like to understand what is going on.

I'm sure it's probably a simple error but I'm just starting out with `CMake` and `CPack` and this seems silly.

### Further Info

I've tried quite a few other combinations and even just setting the `X` in `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR` to 19 is enough to break things.

I've had a look at the generated `CPackSourceConfig.cmake` file and can see the following lines:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "Kappa-19-Source")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "Kappa")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "19")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "19")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "Y")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "Z")
```

I don't know where the "source" came from and assume it should be the `win64` part but it's all not making much sense as to why I can't use a number. Looking inside the NSIS folder I can see that all the files have been assembled into a "Kappa-19-win64" folder, but it just seems to fail at the point of creating the compressed .exe.

### Update

I've managed to break `CPack` in a new way - even with the "XYZ" strings that were working it now fails to build. What I've changed was some packages in the `miniconda` environment that was being packed in the installer.

The installer now fails at the following section in the `project.nsi` file:

```
Section "miniconda" miniconda
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  File /r "${INST_DIR}\miniconda\*.*"
SectionEnd
```

Specifically the `File /r ...` line.

Does anyone know why something in `miniconda` distribution could break `CPack`?